# Is Raspberry PI 4 capable of playing two HD videos simultaneously?

Tags: video, pi-4

RPi 4 can drive two displays with the two HDMI ports. Will it be able to simultaneously decode and play two different HD Quality videos - one on each display?

Answer (score 3):

According to the official specifications it can do 4K video with h265 codec. Or 1080p h264 codec.

I don't believe that it could do two h265 videos.

Comment: So far it looks like only way to know for sure is to try it